# Why refreshing JTable doesn't work after deletion

Tags: java, swing

I have JTable where I can update and delete rows. My problem is that when I want to print out records table refreshes but when I delete/update it doesn't.

PrisonerEvent contains data to delete in database. There is no problem with that. Here is my listener:

```
class DeletePrisonerListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {        

            int row = getSelectedRow();
            PrisonerEvent evt = getPrisonerEvent();
            String message = "Are you sure you want to delete this prisoner?";
            int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, message, "Confirm", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);

            if(option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                prisonerController.removePrisoner(evt.getId());
            }

            tablePanel.getTableModel().fireTableDataChanged();          
        }           
    }
```

And here is my TableModel

```
public class PrisonerTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<Prisoner> db;
private String[] colNames = { "Name", "Surname", "Date of birth", "Height", "Eye color", "Hair color",
            "Country of origin", "Gender"};

public PrisonerTableModel(){
}

public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return colNames[column];
}

public void setData(List<Prisoner> db) {
    this.db = db;
}

public int getColumnCount() {
    return 8;
}

public int getRowCount() {
    return db.size();
}

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    Prisoner prisoner = db.get(row);

    switch(col) {
    case 0:
        return prisoner.getName();
    case 1:
        return prisoner.getSurname();
    case 2:
        return prisoner.getBirth();
    case 3:
        return prisoner.getHeight();
    case 4:
        return prisoner.getEyeColor();
    case 5:
        return prisoner.getHairColor();
    case 6:
        return prisoner.getCountry();
    case 7:
        return prisoner.getGender();

    }

    return null;
}

}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Why implement `AbstractTableModel` rather than extend `DefaultTableModel`? The problem is likely in the table model.

Comment: How is the row actually removed from the `TableModel`?

Answer (score 4):

Your PrisonerTableModel doesn't have a method to remove a row of data from the TableModel. If you want to remove data from the table then you need to remove data from the TableModel. The TableModel will then invoke the `fireTableRowsDeleted(...)` method. Your application code should never invoke a fireXXX(...) method of the TableModel.

The basic logic for removing a row of data would be something like:

```
public void removePrisoner(int row)
{
    db.remove(row);
    fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
}
```

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a more complete example of how to better implement the logic in your TableModel.